# Illegal call of non-static member function - C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to implement an interface in C++ but I get stuck on the problem in the title when I try to use some methods within the derived classes.

The idea of the code is as follows.

```
// ClassHeader.h
#include <vector>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

namespace b
{
   struct mainObj
   {
      virtual ~mainObj(void) {}

      virtual double met(const std::vector<double>& vals) const = 0;
   };


   class Interface
   {
   public:
      Interface(size_t m, const std::vector<double>& tt);

   protected:
      struct OriginalObj;

      size_t _m;
      std::vector<double> _tt;

   private:
      virtual boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj> make_obj(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& T) const = 0;
      virtual const std::vector<double> method1(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& vals) = 0;

   };

   namespace a {
      class Child1 : public Interface
      {
      public:
         // inherit constructor
         // using Interface::Interface;
         Child1(size_t m, const std::vector<double>& tt);

      private:
         struct obj1;
         boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj> make_obj(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& T) const override;

         const std::vector<double> method1(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& vals) override;

      };
   } // namespace a

} // namespace b

// ClassHeader.cpp
#include "ClassHeader.h"

namespace b
{

Interface::Interface(size_t m, const std::vector<double>& tt)
 :  _m(m), _tt(tt) {}

struct Interface::OriginalObj : public mainObj {
   OriginalObj(size_t n, const std::vector<double>& t)
      : _n(n),_t(t) {}

   size_t _n;
   std::vector<double> _t;
};

namespace a {

   const std::vector<double> Child1::method1(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& vals)
   {
      return { static_cast<double>(M), vals[0] };
   }

   struct Child1::obj1 : public Interface::OriginalObj
   {
      // inherit constructor
      using Interface::OriginalObj::OriginalObj;

      Child1* owner;

      double met(const std::vector<double>& vals) const override
      {
         std::vector<double> c = owner->method1(_n, vals);
         return c[0];
      }
   };

   Child1::Child1(size_t m, const std::vector<double>& tt)
      :Interface(m, tt)
   {
      obj1 o1(m, tt); //new construction of o1
      o1.owner = this; // does this initialize all the members as this?
   }

   auto Child1::make_obj(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& T) const
      -> boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj>
   {
      //return boost::make_shared<OriginalObj>(M, T);
      return boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj>{new Child1::obj1(M, T)};
   }

} //namespace a
} // namespace b
```

I know I'm using it without calling it on the object (e.g. `c1.method1(...)`), but I thought that since it was a class method it was somehow implied. Another issue I'm facing is that I cannot make the method static because it is virtual.

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

I changed the code to reproduce the error. now I get the exact same error as in my actual code, in the same exact place. Hope this can help you find what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks again

Comment: There are so many things wrong in this code that it makes it hard to get to the problem you are actually asking about. Please fix all the typos and end your class definitions with `;` etc etc.

Comment: `Class` ?!? Thats not c++

Comment: sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. This is not the actual code, which is a much bigger project and involves functions from other files, more complex structures etc. I was hoping that the spirit of the code snippet I posted was enough to fix the issue. This just to say that I now realize that I made many syntax errors in trying to reproduce the code, which are not present in the original code.

Comment: @YSC I understand. I'll see if I can come up with some reproducible code. My initial hope was some clear logical error that you could see right from the start. In case I can't reproduce the code, I'll delete the question altogether

Comment: @finch Sounds good! You could use the code in JeJo's link as a start since he fixed all the syntax errors for you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll start there for sure. but I also need to try and make the error pop up, because in my actual implementation I had no syntax errors and no warnings but the problem is still present. let's hope to be able to accomplish it

Comment: @finch I see now that you've updated it and I've voted to reopen the question.  I also see that you are trying to call `method1` in `b::a::Child1::obj1`, but `obj1` doesn't have such a member function. `Child1` does, but in order to call that, you need a `Child1` object.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the help. I hadn't noticed that, now I understand what's causing the issue. A question: if I instantiate a `Child1` object like `Child1 c1;` I think the problem would be fixed, but how can I make sure that the object created is the one from which the obj1 is called? Hope the question is clear

Comment: You could store a `Child1* owner;` in the `obj1` object and initialize the `obj1` object (from `Child1`s constructor) with `this`. That way the `obj1` object has a pointer to the object "it belongs" and can then call `owner->method1(...);`

Comment: Thanks again for your precious insight. I implemented what you suggested but now I get a new error, i.e. `error C2280: 'b::a::Child1::obj1::obj1(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. I edited the new code into the post. If I can, I'd bother you for some explanaition as to what's going on and how to fix it. I initially thought it was a problem of defaulted constructor and const objects but I have no const objects initialized

Comment: @YSC thanks for the invaluable help. I tried to compile with just the first solution and indeed I got the error you anticipated. your solution seems to work perfectly. tomorrow I'll test it more in depth but everything seems to work just fine. thanks again!

Comment: Great! converted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj1` does not have a default constructor. This is because it inherits from `OriginalObj` that defines a non-default constructor, rendering the defaulted default constructor non-existant (or deleted):

```
struct Interface::OriginalObj : public mainObj {
   OriginalObj(size_t n, const std::vector<double>& t)
// ...
}
struct Child1::obj1 : public Interface::OriginalObj {
// ...
}
```

Simply defining `OriginalObj() = default;` fixes that problem and set you up to the next challenge, being `boost::make_shared<OriginalObj>(M, T);` tries to construct an object of an abstract class (`met()` is pure virtual). You need to construct an actual `obj1` which can be cast into an `OriginalObj`:

```
auto Child1::make_obj(size_t M, const std::vector<double>& T) const
    -> boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj>
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<OriginalObj>{new Child1::obj1(M, T)};
}
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a24e42e600a92736

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but running the code I got another issue. when trying to execute the line `std::vector<double> c = owner->method1(_n, vals);` the program stops the execution. debugging it seems to me that the `owner` member is not properly created. when we call the make_obj with `new`, are we still considering `owner` instantiate with `this`?

Comment: Indeed, `obj1 o1;` (defined in ``Child1::Child1(size_t, const std::vector<double>&)` creates an `obj1` with uninitialized member variables. You might want to call the other constructor for it: `obj1 o1{m, tt};`

Comment: Your program architecture might be a tad more complex than your level in C++ allows. ThHere is no shame in simplifying stuff. On the contrary, I'd consider a program to be better the simpler it gets.

Comment: I did that, but the program interrupts anyway. I edited the code to show what I tried. in particular it seems like `owner` does not populate with all the fields this have and is in some undefined state. what am I missing? I also tried to define an obj1 inside the `make_obj` function and then assigning that owner with `this`, but I get a conversion error....

Comment: I understand the architecture is a bit complex, but I inherited part of the structure from the existing library and I thought this was the best way to achieve a kind of split between objects. in fact I have a second child  (let's call it `Child2`) which is almost identical to `Child1` except it has a different `method1` which I now see is not override as it should (I will edit the original code to be more precise)